# MYSQL extract uppercase words

Tags: mysql, extract, uppercase, words

I am trying to extract words which are in uppercase and lowercase.
Example, in single column(Full_name) having first and last name values, here I need to separate them as first and last names, first names always have in initial capital letter and last names have always all letters in uppercase.

```
Full_Name:
---------
abc ABC
pqr RTF
```

now I need separate them in 2 different columns as below

```
First_name  Last_name
---------   --------
 abc        ABC
 pqr        RTF
```

Thank you very much for you inputs in advance.

Comment: You can only get the data from database . If you wanna seperate it you have to use php code .

Comment: actually I required SQL statement for the above output.

Comment: It has only three names ah ? like `Agns AZERI DEB`

Comment: @Nick...tried with substring functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(Full_Name,LOCATE(' ',Full_Name)) AS First_name,
SUBSTRING(Full_Name,LOCATE(' ',Full_Name)) AS Last_name
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Check [<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bae9c/2)

Comment: Check your fiddle and OP is result its miss matched

Comment: doesnt do what OP want, dps should be first name. i think you cant solve this without REGEXP.

Comment: I know Last record mistmatch but there is no similarities between given input.

Comment: @Sadikhasan..the query is not working for all cases for example: Alain Dps DENI....here 'Alain Dps' should go in first_name, 'DENI' should go in last_name....thank you already.. at least you provided basic query which will help me to play...will be appreciated if you provide the complete corrected query.

Comment: @All...Are there any solution by extracting words which are in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in MySQL is to use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(full_name, ' ', 1) as First_Name,
       substring_index(full_name, ' ', -1) as Last_Name
from table t;
```

EDIT:

I missed the names with multiple parts.

```
select substring_index(full_name, ' ', 1) as First_Name,
       trim(substring(full_name,
                      length(substring_index(full_name, ' ', 1))
                     )
           ) as Last_Name
from table t;
```

Comment: @user3864232 . . . I understand.  I edited the answer, but it still won't work for multi-part first names, if those exist.  Extracting substrings based on case can be a pain in MySQL.

Comment: @Linoff....thanks you for your inputs...but I am getting wrong results for simple names as below cases: case 1:  Sam PUSALA, output is Sam as fisrt_name(Which is correct), m PUSALA as last_name which is not correct as I am getting extra letter 'm' and space..........case 2:not working if first name as 2 words as you said..cas3: sometimes full_name is having only with upercase words which means only lastname.....it will be great if you provide me any help.